# Chrome browser keeps crashing when running on android emulator in docker container

Tags: docker, android-emulator, appium

I want to create a setup to utilize docker container to run android emulators which will connect to hub via appium. 
I was able to create a customized docker image based on [this project](https://github.com/typemismatch/android-emulator) 
It will start a docker container which will start an android emulator and then connect it to a hub via appium.

Now I ran into issue that no matter on what android emulator abi i use (default or google_apis) and the default chrome browser or manually installed one always crash when I try to click and open it.

The Android SDK i am running has android-24 api, and i was using the following images: 
sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-24 
sys-img-armeabi-v7a-google_apis-24

When i manually install the chrome browser i instilled arm version for android-24 api

I have a few questions:

1. Anyone run into similar issue for chrome browser keeps crashing?
2. Will my docker setup work?
3. Is there any other android emulator in docker container solution which can connect to outside hub via appium?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Using x86 instead of x86_64 works for me.  However, there are not x86 versions of the latest api versions.  For these, I just install firefox and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the following two issues:

1. My graphic card driver was not installed in the host system (Ubuntu 16.04.03 x64) and my current user was not in the group "video".

The symptom of the missing graphics card driver was the following logged line in the "Android Device Monitor" (for all googlers):

```
chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(263)] eglChooseConfig failed with error
```

2. I used the wrong emulator and chrome architecture.

After I used an android image with the architecture x86 (and not *x86_64*) and a google chrome version with the architecture x86 (and not *arm* or *arm64 + arm*) runs everything fine.

Finally a good article about how chrome is updated in the emulator: https://www.inflectra.com/support/knowledgebase/kb276.aspx